# Converting a nested subquery into a simple query

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

There are two tables 'employees' and 'allocation'. Can anybody help me to convert this nested query into a simple query (using joins or anything). I mean i don't want a nested query. Here is the query which works fine.

```
select emp_id, emp_name from employees 
where emp_id not in (select emp_id from allocation 
            where emp_id is not null 
            and date_assignedUpto is null 
            group by emp_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this if you really do not want to use `NOT IN` query :

```
 SELECT e.emp_id, e.emp_name FROM employees e 
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT emp_id FROM allocation 
            WHERE emp_id IS NOT NULL 
            AND date_assignedUpto IS NULL 
            GROUP BY emp_id) a 
 ON e.emp_id= a.emp_id;
```

Comment: Neither your qeury is not equivalent to my query. It is giving a different answer. btw thanks, now i have some idea to built the query.

Comment: Sorry,There is NOT IN in the query which I thought IN only..Go throught updated answer.....